# How can i split string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to split string into address, city, state and zip code but unable to split successfully.

Here is my code:

```
address =  "4502 150th Pl SE, Bellevue, WA 98006"
my_add = address.split(',')
street = my_add[0] 
city = my_add[1]
state_zip = my_add[2]
state_zip = state_zip
state = state_zip.split(' ')
print(street)
print(city)
print(state_zip)
print(state)
# 4502 150th Pl SE
#  Bellevue
#  WA 98006
# ['', 'WA', '98006']
```

I expect that address will be split as:

- address : 4502 150th Pl SE
- city :  Bellevue
- state: WA
- zipcode: 98006

can anyone help me to find best possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to include what the actual results from your code are, as that will helps us understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting some extra spaces in there, and since you are splitting on spaces, you end up with `my_add[2]` containing three elements: an empty string (comes before the first space), your state, and your zip code. You can add `.strip()` to your code to fix this:

```
street = my_add[0].strip()
city = my_add[1].strip()
state_zip = my_add[2].strip()  # remove extra spaces
state_zip = state_zip.split(' ')  # now split on space to get state and zip
state = state_zip[0]  # first element: state
zip_code = state_zip[1]  # second element: zip
print(street)
print(city)
print(state_zip)
print(state)
print(zip_code)
# 4502 150th Pl SE
# Bellevue
# ['WA', '98006']
# WA
# 98006
```

Comment: Can you give me best possible solution of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559962/how-can-i-get-only-name-and-contact-number-from-div

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that a comma is always followed by a space, you can do this:

```
address =  "4502 150th Pl SE, Bellevue, WA 98006"

street, city, state_info = address.split(", ")
state, zipcode = state_info.split(" ")

print("address:", street)
print("city:", city)
print("state:", state)
print("zipcode:", zipcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution would be the code below:

```
address = "4502 150th Pl SE, Bellevue, WA 98006"
my_add = address.split(',')
street = my_add[0]
city = my_add[1]
state_zip = my_add[2]
state_zip_split = state_zip.split(' ')
state_zip = state_zip_split[2]
state = state_zip_split[1]
print("Street: ", street)
print("City: ", city)
print("State Zip: ", state_zip)
print("State: ", state)
```

You defined `state_zip` as an array, you needed to split it one more time to get the state and zip code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
>>> address = "4502 150th Pl SE, Bellevue, WA 98006"
>>> my_add = address.split(',')
>>> street = my_add[0]
>>> street
'4502 150th Pl SE'
>>> city = my_add[1].strip()
>>> city
'Bellevue'
>>> state_zip = my_add[2].split()[1]
>>> state_zip
'98006'
>>> state = my_add[2].split()[0]
>>> state
'WA'
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this

```
import re
re.split(', ', address)
*add1, city, state, zipcode = [x for x in re.split('[ ,]', address) if x!='']
add1 = ' '.join(add1)
```