# How can i get only name and contact number from div?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get name and contact number from div and div has three span, but the problem is that sometime div has only one span, some time two and sometime three span.

- First span has name.
- Second span has other data.
- Third span has contact number

> Here is HTML

```
<div class="ds-body-small" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_3864">
 <span class="listing-field" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_3863">beth 
 budinich</span>
 <span class="listing-field"><a href="http://Www.redfin.com" 
 target="_blank">See listing website</a></span>
 <span class="listing-field" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_4443">(206) 
 793-8336</span>
</div>
```

Here is my Code

```
try:
  name= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='listing-field'][1]")
  name = name.text.strip()
  print("name : " + name)
except:
  print("Name are missing")
  name = "N/A"

try:
  contact_info= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='listing- 
  field'][3]")
  contact_info = contact_info.text.strip()
  print("contact info : " + contact_info)
except:
  print("contact_info are missing")
  days = "N/A"
```

My code is not giving me correct result. Can anyone provide me best possible solution. Thanks

Comment: _My code is not giving me correct result_ Show us the results, and explain how they aren't what you want.

Comment: @JohnGordon if div has first two span then second one is assigned to contact number.  Can you give me correct code that would give me name and contact number if div has 1,2 or 3 span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate throw contacts and check, if there's child `a` element and if match phone number pattern:

```
contacts = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.listing-field")

contact_name = []
contact_phone = "N/A"
contact_web = "N/A"

for i in range(0, len(contacts)):
    if len(contacts[i].find_elements_by_tag_name("a")) > 0:
        contact_web = contacts[i].find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
    elif re.search("\\(\\d+\\)\\s+\\d+-\\d+", contacts[i].text):
        contact_phone = contacts[i].text
    else:
        contact_name.append(contacts[i].text)

contact_name = ", ".join(contact_name) if len(contact_name) > 0 else "N/A"
```

Output:

> contact_name: ['Kevin Howard', 'Howard enterprise']
>   
> contact_phone: '(206) 334-8414'

The page has captcha. To scrape better to use [requests](/questions/tagged/requests), all information provided in json format.

Comment: #xpath code is giving me error. <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="90b9857b-0b38-45a5-91a4-5e84c070c1ff", element="e8085d93-fb13-40e8-840a-c4e9dd08e3ab")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="90b9857b-0b38-45a5-91a4-5e84c070c1ff", element="e8085d93-fb13-40e8-840a-c4e9dd08e3ab")>

Comment: It's not error, WebElement returns. Check updated code, added `.text` to get text

Comment: Still i'm facing problem, if div has only span then first and last span text will be same. if div have one span then other variable should be null.

Comment: there is a syntax error in this line:  contact_phone = contacts[i] if re.search("\\(\\d+\\)\\s+\\d+-\\d+", contacts[i])

Comment: Fixed: `contact_phone = contacts[i].text`

Comment: Can you share url?

Comment: url-1: https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4501-Cascadia-Ave-S-Seattle-WA-98118/49071635_zpid/

Comment: url-2:  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/4501-Cascadia-Ave-S-Seattle-WA-98118/49071635_zpid/

Comment: url-3: https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/7432-Tacoma-Ave-S-Tacoma-WA-98408/49228009_zpid/

Comment: Because in your [link](https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/7432-Tacoma-Ave-S-Tacoma-WA-98408/49228009_zpid/) only one span and it's number

Comment: Use updated second code. Code will collect names as list.

Comment: Please accept correct answers for this and previous questions you asked

Comment: Thanks a lot Sers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191454/discussion-between-zubair-farooq-and-sers).

Answer (score 0):

```
#sudharsan
# April 07 2019
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text ='''<div class="ds-body-small" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_3864">
<span class="listing-field" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_3863">beth 
budinich</span>
<span class="listing-field"><a href="http://Www.redfin.com" 
target="_blank">See listing website</a></span>
<span class="listing-field" id="yui_3_18_1_1_1554645615890_4443">(206) 
793-8336</span>
</div>'''
# the given sample html is stored as a input in variable called "text"
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
main = soup.find(class_="listing-field")
# Now the spans with class name "listing-field" is stored as list in "main"
print main[0].text
# it will print the first span element
print main[-1].text
# it will print the last span element
#Thank you
# if you like the code "Vote for it"
```

Comment: Code looks good, can you re-write in Python Selenium? because i'm using selenium browser

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Actually you can use the above code in selenium also, by scraping the html content using the selenium option "driver.page_source" and storing in "text" variable instead of that sample html text. The rest of the code is similar for scraping